# What does this mean -> ClassA( obj as MovieClip ) or var var_a : ClassA = new SomeOtherClass()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I really get confused with these type of statements :

What does this mean :

1. when casting :

   `var xyz =  ClassA( obj as MovieClip );`
2. when declaring/defining :

   `var xyz:ClassA  = new SomeOtherClass();`

I mean, how 2 different classes are used in the same statements above ? Is this possible because of inheritance relationship ?

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xyz:ClassA = new SomeOtherClass()
```

xyz is declared as having the type ClassA, so this assignment will only work if SomeOtherClass is a subclass of ClassA.  If not, an error will be thrown at compile time.

```
var xyz = ClassA( obj as MovieClip )
```

The result of this statement is a double cast: First, obj is cast to MovieClip, then to ClassA.  If any of those two types is not in obj's type hierarchy, the result is `null`.
Unless obj is not a MovieClip (in which case, trying to cast `null` to ClassA will cause a null pointer exception at runtime), there will not be an error, because you could assign anything to xyz - no variable type was specified.

Comment: Why i ever need something like this ?
    var xyz:ClassA = new SomeOtherClass()

Comment: When you inherit a class that has a variable of type ClassA, and your inherited class needs to use a subtype of it. A well-known example for this way to handle types (though not a declaration) is `DisplayObjectContainer.addChild (DisplayObject)` - you can pass in a Sprite, a Shape, a MovieClip, etc. -- they all inherit DisplayObject, so they all can be added to the display list.